# Node.JS export ES Object into NPM package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have an ES5 object/function that I'm trying to use inside an NPM package. That object is in a namespace such as

```
 MY_NAMESPACE.myObject = function(){...}
```

where MY_NAMESPACE is just an object. For the web, I'd just link a JS file where the object/function is and then do

```
 let whatever = new MY_NAMESPACE.myObject();
```

I have saved the source as `my_function.js`.

I created a npm package like so, in order to install it in my app

```
 {
       "name": "whatever",
       "version": "1.0.0",
       "description": "",  
       "main": "index.js",
       "scripts": {
              "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
       },  
       "author": "whatever",
        "license": "Apache-2.0",  
        "exports" :{
             "./my_function.js" : "./my_function.js"
       }
   }
```

When I install the package locally, I can see that `my_function.js` is in `node_modules/whatever`

How can I now reference/import `my_function.js` inside my app, then be able to call

```
  let whatever = new MY_NAMESPACE.myObject();
```

Some of the **awful** Node.JS documentation mentions .mjs files to add ES modules but can't find examples/tutorials... I'm also trying to **not add anything** like `module.exports` to the `my_function.js` because that file is updated constantly and used in a web/front end environment as well.

So basically, I'm trying to attach a .js file inside a NPM package and would like to have its content available in my app. I'm hoping that, adding something to the `index.js` of the package would render the objects declared in the file, available across my app... I just don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Could you explain why using `module.exports` it's a problem for web/front?

Comment: For example, lodash can be used on both front and backend sides. You can see how [source code looks like](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/defer.js), and then it's building to [use "module.exports"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnTJx.png)

Comment: "because that file is updated constantly and used in a web/front end environment as well." It was pretty clear - we do not wish to manipulate this file and this is the very request of this question.

Comment: what is the problem to use "module.exports" on  web/front end environment?

Comment: We do not wish to inject anything to this file and exploring if it can be done

Comment: How would you link the file?

Comment: I may be able to suggest somthing, I think I have a decent Idea of what you are asking, but I need to know about this file. How would you link the file, (using an actual link, sumthin like `fs.linkSync(pathOrig, pathAlias)` ) or do you mean assign the filespath? And what kind of file is it? What do you do with the file? And how do you go about updating it? Obviously this file is extremely important, and the extension you desire needs to be built around it, but the SO community needs more to go on in order to be able to give you an answer. You got 2 days of bounty time left.

Comment: I suggest you do an edit and try to explain in depth about the file, how you "link it to the object", what the file does, and try to answer everything i asked above, if your thorough you might be surprised by how many good answers you get.

Comment: It is linked by adding to the exports node of package.json as the doc suggest. There is no need to know what's inside the file. Irrelevant. It's just an object, simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

One pattern to expose the function would be using [module.exports](https://nodejs.dev/learn/expose-functionality-from-a-nodejs-file-using-exports) like this:

```
# my_function.js

MY_NAMESPACE = {};
MY_NAMESPACE.myObject = function(){...};

module.exports = MY_NAMESPACE;
```

And then it can be consumed by another module in the same directory as:

```
# consumer JS file

let MY_NAMESPACE = require('./my_function');

let test = new MY_NAMESPACE.myObject();
```

If you really want to package up my_function.js in a separate node.js package (for example, if you need to share it between projects), there are a few additional steps to take. [This documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules) is a good starting point.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to do, package it

Comment: Do I have to add anything to the index.js of my package ?

Comment: You don't need to add anything to index.js if you just want to import the file locally, as shown in the example. If you want to build a bundled package (e.g. for use with npm, using a package.json) then yes the package would probably have its own index.js that exports everything. But if you're just asking "how do I build a node.js package" you should look at the documentation I linked above to get the overview.

Comment: Consider writing a new question that more clearly explains where you are stuck in the process of building an npm package. For example, show the package.json you've created, and point out a specific step in a link link the one I provided that is not clear or that you are having trouble with.